# Trying to print the below Grid in Python

Tags: python, gridview, grid

I am trying to print a string as a Grid as per below image.

[image]
I understand there will be a for loop and I have got the  Grid display elements as:

```
HORIZONTAL_WALL = "-"
VERTICAL_WALL = "|"
CORNER = "+"
EMPTY = " " 

for i in range(len(puzzle)):
```

Would anybody please help me by showing a way to get this done.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add, what is a puzzle variable you used in the loop??

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with the python external packages, here is a way of doing that

**termtables: https://github.com/nschloe/termtables**

- with texttable you can control horizontal/vertical align, border style and data types.

```
!pip install termtables
```

```
import termtables as tt

string = "nevagonagiveu up"

# Python3 program to Split string into characters
def split(word):
    return [char for char in word] 
    
puzzle = split(string)
```

Convert into a 2d array using numpy

```
import numpy as np
puzzle_arr = np.array(puzzle).reshape(-1, 4)

puzzle_arr
```

```
grid = tt.to_string(
    puzzle_arr,
    style=tt.styles.ascii_thin,
    # alignment="ll",
    # padding=(0, 1),
)
print(grid)
```

**Output:**

```
+---+---+---+---+
| n | e | v | a |
+---+---+---+---+
| g | o | n | a |
+---+---+---+---+
| g | i | v | e |
+---+---+---+---+
| u |   | u | p |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks,but I am not supposed to use external package.